# React Native: expo start caused throw err: Cannot find module

Tags: react-native

PLease help, I started a new React Native app. I followed the React Native instruction on how to set up dev env. https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
I installed the latest Node. Then in my project folder:
I ran '''npm install -g expo-cli'''
then, 'expo init AwesomeProject'
cd AwesomeProject
npm start

When I did npm start, that's when I saw this error message. I tried to search online for solutions. I reinstall Node, add a new path for Node, nothing seems to help. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE****. Steps to resolve above issue, update Node.js, errors show up when using Git Bash, switch to command prompt, then do 'expo start' instead of 'npm start', now it works.

Git Bash:

```
$ expo start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\wendy\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: did you tried to create your app with `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` ?

Comment: or if you really want to use expo, try this: `npm install -g expo-cli --force`

Comment: @poPaTheGuru thank you. I tried npm install -g expo-cli --force, but when I do 'expo init AwesomeProject', same error message as above.

Comment: do you have a `node_modules` folder in your project? if not, run `npm install` then try again. Or try to uninstall expo-cli and install it again

Comment: @poPaTheGuru yes i do have node_modules. I deleted once, rerun npm install, same error message. This time it also said "Could not determine Node.js install directory
" on the bottom of the error message.  I uninstall expo-cli and install it again, when I run expo init, that's when the same error shows up again